# ClickOnce to Dropbox

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, dropbox

I'd like to use Dropbox as a location where I deploy my WPF application with ClickOnce. I want to use shared folder so that only those people who have access to that shared folder would have access to the application, but nobody else would not.

Are there some guildines available how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder on Dropbox, where the application will be deployed from.
Create a folder on your computer, where you will save the ClickOnce package before uploading it to Dropbox.

Run the Visual Studio Publish Wizard. (Under the *Build* menu, click *Publish ProjectName*)

- When asked **Where do you want to publish the application?**, enter the path to the local folder.
- Then, on the **How will users install the application?** page, select **From a Web site**, and enter the URL of the folder on Dropbox.
- Finish the Publish Wizard appropriately for your application.

Finally, copy the contents of the local folder to the folder on Dropbox.
You may configure the folder's permissions as needed inside Dropbox.

For more information on ClickOnce publishing: [Publish a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is possible. For this to work, you would need Dropbox to serve the contents of a folder but only serve those contents to a particular group of users. Dropbox doesn't have a permissions model that would support this.